# $('#notificationClick').click not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

so I'm trying to make this works here is the jquery+php.

When I try to trigle the click in jquery it doesnt even does the "alert()".

PHP(Updated):

```
$MSG_Notification_sql = mysqli_query($Connection, "SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE user_id='".$bzInfo['id']."'");

while ($MSG_Notification_row = mysqli_fetch_array($MSG_Notification_sql)){        

    $MSG_Notification_rows[] = $MSG_Notification_row;        

}

foreach ($MSG_Notification_rows as $MSG_Notification_row){                

    $bzWhen = date('d-m-Y H:m:i', strtotime($MSG_Notification_row['when']));


    echo '<form method="POST">
            <div class="notificationClick notification-messages info">
                <div class="user-profile"> 
                    <img src="assets/img/profiles/d.jpg"  alt="" data-src="assets/img/profiles/d.jpg" data-src-retina="assets/img/profiles/d2x.jpg" width="35" height="35">
                </div>
                <div class="message-wrapper">
                  <div class="heading"> '.$MSG_Notification_row['title'].'</div>
                  <div class="description"> '.$MSG_Notification_row['description'].' </div>
                  <div class="date pull-left"> '.$bzWhen.'</div>
                </div>                               
                <input name="notificationID" value="'.$MSG_Notification_row['id'].'" style="display: none" />                
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </form>';

}
```

Javascript(Updated):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.notificationClick').click(function(event){                 

                alert('Ok');

        // get the form data
        // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the class or id also)
        var formData = $('#notificationClick').serialize();

        // process the form
        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url         : '../../class/notifications/msgs_del.php', // the url where we want to POST
            data        : formData, // our data object                         
            dataType    : 'json' // what type of data do we expect back from the server

        })
            // using the done promise callback
            .done(function(data) {
                // log data to the console so we can see
                console.log(data); 

                window.location = '/?page=messages&sub=inbox&bx=preview&id='+ data.notificationID +'';

            });                                                

            event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Can anybody help me please? I'm trying to complete this but nothing :(

Comment: Element `id`s must be unique on the page. Use a class instead and see where that gets you.

Comment: ids must be unique write class selector event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First as the others say, ids need to be singular. So use the class you already have. Now inside, you need to use the current form that you clicked on, not all the forms.

```
$('.notification-messages').click(function(event){      //<-- change to class           
    var formData = $(this).closest("form").serialize();  //change to this
    ...
```

If you are loading these dynamically, you need to use event delegation

```
$(document).on("click", '.notification-messages', function(event){       
    var formData = $(this).closest("form").serialize();
    ...
```

Comment: @TimVermaelen whoops! fixed.

Comment: ye i deleted that comment, just update your first closet as well ^^

Answer (score 0):

You're using ID, you can only bind click to 1 id not multiple ids.

You should use the class to bind the .click function.

Comment: Still not working! The .click() event isnt not workin with class:

<div class="notificationClick notification-messages info">

Comment: @ThomasLopes how are you binding the .click now? this: $('#notificationClick') should be $('.notificationClick')

Comment: Yes I know, I've changed that too!

Comment: @ThomasLopes Could you update your answers code with your current code? so I can look into it.

Comment: live has been deprecated and unusable for a LONG time.

Comment: @epascarello I didn't know that, let me update again.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the timestamp to your id to make it unique (separated by an `_` if you like) and change your selector for the click event to `$('[id*="notificationClick_"]')`

On the other hand, you might want to use a class instead, that's what it's there for:

```
$(".notification-messages")
```